# How to set my own Content-Length when downloading files with fixed size from the internet?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, curl, wget

I want to download 100 files that are 1GB each from a website but the file size is unknown since there is no Content-Length set in headers. My download is slow and unstable. When the download crash for a few seconds in the middle of the download, it starts downloading the next file and leave the previous file incomplete.

Normally I use `wget -c` or `curl -C` to resume partially downloaded files. It's possible to set my own Content-Length for each file to 1GB with wget or curl? If that's possible wget and curl won't go straight to the next file after a few seconds lag. Hopefully resuming the download will work like that too

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
wget --header="Content-Length: 1099511627776" ...
```

According to the man-page:

```
       As of Wget 1.10, this option can be used to override headers otherwise generated
       automatically.
```

Comment: I tried but wget still says: `Length: unspecified [application/7z, application/octet-stream]` while downloading and when the download crash I need to restart the whole download. So it doesn't work for me